# Create an interactive slide transition between view controllers

Tags: ios, swift, transition

I have been working with page and tab based applications for a while now, however, the transitions haven't been doing it for me. I am looking for a transition similar to the one when swiping through the pages of apps on your iPhone. The transition moves with your finger and if your change directions halfway the transition will move back.

I had no clue how to approach this. So before I start trying to create a complex solution, is there an easy or trivial solution? Thanks for the help.

Edit: the difference from the page view controller is that I am looking for a slide transition rather than a page application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You said:

> the difference from the page view controller is that I am looking for a slide transition rather than a page application"

See the [`transitionStyle`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uipageviewcontroller/1614092-transitionstyle#declarations) property of you `UIPageViewController`, which can give you the `.slide` transition you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write an interactive custom view controller transition that does what you describe — but it's a lot of work. However, you are describing exactly what a UIPageViewController does for you already (in scroll style). So why not use a UIPageViewController?

[image]

Comment: My problem with the page view controller is that there are actually pages it seems quite awkward. So is there no way to keep it as a slide transition.

Comment: It sound as if maybe you don't understand how to use the page view controller? It has two different styles. In scroll style, it doesn't look like "pages" at all! I can show you an example project that lets you do an interactive slide transition between the view controllers of a tab view controller, for example, but it looks exactly like a UIPageViewController in scroll style. Maybe you should learn a bit more about UIPageViewController before you criticize it.